# How can i call a function for a button that is not written as first in my jquery code

Tags: jquery, button

I am still a learner and this question may be a very easy one to answer.
I have created three buttons with a specific function. One button will display a div box, the second button will hide a div box, third button will toggle fade to a `h1` element. my code works and does what i want but it only works the way i want after i have clicked the third button. I have noticed that in my written code the third button its function is written as first in order. That is why only the third button at a fresh webpage can call for its function and the other buttons not. After the function is called with the third button then the other 2 remaining buttons work. My code is here

```
<body>
    <h2>Hello world</h2>
    <h1>welkom to this test</h1>
    <div id="blok"></div>
    <button id="one">hide box</button>&nbsp;
    <button id="two">display box</button>&nbsp;
    <button id="three">hide/unhide h1</button>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#three").click(function(){
            $("h1").fadeToggle();
            $("#one").click(function(){
                $("#blok").fadeOut(1000);
                    $("#two").click(function(){
                        $("#blok").fadeIn(1000);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to put your `click` events inside of one another. Simply make each of them their own, independent function, like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#one").click(function() {
    $("#blok").fadeOut(1000);
  });
  $("#two").click(function() {
    $("#blok").fadeIn(1000);
  });
  $("#three").click(function() {
    $("h1").fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Omg, how could i not see that? Thanks for your superfast response and help.

Comment: Probably you couldn't see it because of not indenting your code at all, look at your code in the question after adding identation

Comment: No problem! And yeah, I'd take @Mi-Creativity's advice, code indentation is a habit essential to programming

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Yeah my bad for not indenting code. I just didn't think it would be that necessary for this particulary written code as it is just a simple testing and very easy to read its function. I still have my lesson learned and will in the future questions use the indenting style.